# Scroll div content horizontally using left and right arrow in html

Tags: html, css

Attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thcCZ.png) contains the html code part where I need to add a left right scroll able button. However i cannot see the complete images one after another. Currently it shows an animated view. In addition to the same I need next prev button also.

```
<section class="sponser-area section-padding" id="sponsors">
    <div id="sponsors" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="page-title">
                    <h2>Insurance Partners</h2>
                    <p>Consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy</p>
                </div>
                <div class="sponser-items">
                    <div class="sponser-item">
                        <a href="#" title="sensile medical"><img src="images/sponser/01_sponser.jpg" alt="Helth plus"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sponser-item">
                        <a href="#" title="medical"><img src="images/sponser/02_sponser.jpg" alt="Helth plus"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sponser-item">
                        <a href="#" title="medical logo"><img src="images/sponser/03_sponser.jpg" alt="Helth plus"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sponser-item">
                        <a href="#" title="hospital logo"><img src="images/sponser/04_sponser.jpg" alt="Helth plus"></a>
                    </div>                                                  
                    <div class="sponser-item">
                        <a href="#" title="hospital logo"><img src="images/sponser/15_sponser.jpg" alt="Helth plus"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sponser-item">
                        <a href="#" title="hospital logo"><img src="images/sponser/16_sponser.jpg" alt="Helth plus"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sponser-item">
                        <a href="#" title="hospital logo"><img src="images/sponser/17_sponser.jpg" alt="Helth plus"></a>

                    <div class="sponser-item">
                        <a href="#" title="hospital logo"><img src="images/sponser/23_sponser.jpg" alt="Helth plus"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
               <a class="left slide-control" href="#home_slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right slide-control" href="#home_slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code *as text* directly in the question.

Comment: Can you add your css as well?

Comment: i have added the code part with what i tried

Comment: .sponser-area a img {
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}

.sponser-area a:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2)
}

Comment: I am not sure i clearly understand your requirement. 
If it is a carousel you are looking for using bootstrap, I found an example for it.
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=carousel

Comment: https://www.codeply.com/go/y1iGO88Z5w Here is the modified version with animation.

Comment: This is looking cool. in addition it has quite different view  when comparing to what is currently there. i meant to say a single row contains 4 images before and now it has only one at a time.